# Триггер для MS SQL

Tags: триггер, sql-server

Приветствую.

Помогите разобраться с триггерами на языке SQL.

У меня есть 2 таблицы "Подкатегории_продуктов" и "Продукты".
**Столбцы**
Подкатегории_продуктов: id, name, count_products
Продукты: id, name, price, id_подкатегории_продуктов

Необходимо при добавлении или удалении строки в таблицу Продукты обновлять количество продуктов в подкатегории.

Например, у нас есть 2 подкатегории "name = первая, count_products = 0", "name = вторая, count_products = 0". При добавлении в таблицу продуктов 3 строк: "name = пр1, price = 1, id_подкатегории_продуктов = 1", "name = пр2, price = 2, id_подкатегории_продуктов = 1", "name = пр3, price = 5, id_подкатегории_продуктов = 2".

Таблица подкатегорий должна выглядеть

"name = первая, count_products = 2", "name = вторая, count_products = 1"

Вот, что я написал, но он почему-то не срабатывает для одной строки, и я не понимаю, как сделать, при добавлении нескольких строк как пройтись по каждой строке в inserted?

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
    countproductscategories
ON
    dbo.products
AFTER
    INSERT
AS
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.product_subcategories
    SET count_products = count_products + 1
    WHERE dbo.product_subcategories.id = (SELECT id FROM inserted)
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

> WHERE dbo.product_subcategories.id = (SELECT id FROM inserted)

А что у вас хранится в поле **id** таблицы с продуктами? Если это идентификатор продукта, тогда вы обновляете подкатегорию в соответствии с идентификатором свежевставленного продукта, что не совсем корректно. Должно быть как-то так:

```
WHERE dbo.product_subcategories.id = (SELECT subcategory_id FROM inserted)
```

---

**2.**

Естественно, что оно у вас не работает со множественной вставкой, поскольку

> IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1

Попробуйте вот так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
    countproductscategories
ON
    dbo.products
AFTER
    INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE u
  SET
    count_products = count_products + inserted2.cnt
  FROM

    (SELECT count(1) AS cnt, subcategory_id FROM inserted GROUP BY subcategory_id) inserted2

    INNER JOIN dbo.product_subcategories u ON u.id = inserted2.subcategory_id
END;
```

или же нормализуйте схему данных, тогда вообще отпадёт необходимость в данном триггере.